# rpm spec: conditional require based of distro version

Tags: redhat, centos5, rpm

I'm trying to write a single rpm spec for RHEL/CentOS/SL 5 and 6. This spec is for python app, so there is no differences in build process. But on RHEL/CentOS5 I need to add one additional dependency.

How would I define dependency only for el5? I've tried following:

```
%if 0%{?redhat} == 5 || 0%{?centos} == 5
Requires:   kmod-coretemp
%endif
```

Does not work (build on CentOS5 does not adds kmod-coretemp dependency).

I've tried also following:

```
%if %{?dist} == "el5"
```

It reports with syntax error. I'm sure dist macro is set and contains 'el5'. But I'm not sure what is the syntax of if conditionals in rpm? rpmguide does not have detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dist tag packaging guidelines.](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/DistTag/)

Comment: hm, it doesn't show the tags for centos in that page.

Comment: @dothebart: "RHEL n (all variants)"

Answer (score 9):

The Fedora wiki, as usual, provides the best guidelines about packaging. Take a look at the [Packaging:DistTag](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DistTag#Conditionals) page. You can use the `%{el5}` variable and a shorthand conditional to ensure that the relevent `Require` line is used when building packages for EL5.

```
%{?el5:Requires: kmod-coretemp}
```

You'll probably want to add the `dist` tag to the version field to avoid later confusion between packages:

```
Release: 1%{?dist}
```

See [Purpose of the Dist Tag](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DistTag#Purpose_of_the_Dist_Tag).

Comment: Thanks! Well, my system does not have this for some reason, but I've defined macro manually. Sorry, marking Ignacio answer as accepted, as it was first one.

Comment: If they're not present then you may need to install the package `redhat-rpm-config` from Yum.

Comment: It's installed, but still no macros. I believe it's centos-specific, as on another rhel5 machines they are in place.